# In SQL Server, how can I update values based on last occurrence of the series

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used the `LEAD()` function in SQL Server to get as far as I could. I have patients, labs and dates. I have figured out how to get the last status and the 2nd to the last status of a completed (on-time) appointment. My problem is updating all the values before the NEVER or EVENTUALLY to be the same as the last entry.

```
EverDone Column
ON-TIME = the test was done 
EVENTUALLY = means the very next test was completed
NEVER = the last test was never done
```

I need to set all the --- prior to an EVENTUALLY to be EVENTUALLY. Such as the LDL item for 2002

I need to set all the --- prior to a NEVER to be NEVER, such as the BLOOD item

But the criteria cannot be the very last of the series, as in the LDL test.  The very last Test was never done, but the status prior to eventually was done.

```
Name           Item   date        Status    EverDone
----------------------------------------------------
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  6/6/2002    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  1/6/2003    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  7/8/2003    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  6/15/2004   LAPSED    NEVER
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    8/19/2002   LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    10/2/2002   LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/12/2002  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/12/2002  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/16/2002  LAPSED    EVENTUALLY
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/26/2002  COMP      ON-TIME
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    1/8/2004    LAPSED    NEVER
```

Comment: You don't need any special functions, you can do it with a sub-select or a self-join.

Comment: I am failry new to sql.  do you have an example of this.

Comment: is there a primary key on this table?  Or do you need to use a combination of Name, Item, and date?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key, this will work -

```
UPDATE TableName
SET EverDone = 'EVENTUALLY'
WHERE KeyName in (SELECT b.KeyName 
                FROM TableName a
                  join TableName b on a.Name = b.Name 
                      and a.Item = b.Item 
                      and a.Date < b.Date
                      bEverDone = '---'
                WHERE a.EverDone = 'EVENTUALLY')
```

If you don't have a primary key, this will work -

```
UPDATE TableName
SET EverDone = 'EVENTUALLY'
WHERE CONCAT(Name, Item, Date) in (SELECT CONCAT(b.Name, b.Item, b.Date)
                FROM TableName a
                  join TableName b on a.Name = b.Name 
                      and a.Item = b.Item 
                      and a.Date < b.Date
                      bEverDone = '---'
                WHERE a.EverDone = 'EVENTUALLY')
```

BUT - if your data looks like this:

```
Name           Item   date        Status    EverDone
----------------------------------------------------
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  6/6/2002    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  1/6/2003    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  7/8/2003    LAPSED    ---
ZZNIN, CHEEZE  BLOOD  6/15/2004   LAPSED    NEVER
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/10/2001  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/12/2001  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/16/2001  LAPSED    ON-TIME    
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    8/19/2002   LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    10/2/2002   LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/12/2002  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/12/2002  LAPSED    ---
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/16/2002  LAPSED    EVENTUALLY
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    12/26/2002  COMP      ON-TIME
SLAYER, JONES  LDL    1/8/2004    LAPSED    NEVER
```

The rows for Slayer before Slayer-LDL-12/16/01 will also get updated.  I'm assuming that is ok.

Comment: I'm hoping there is a better way to do that first one - CONCAT is the first thing that came to mind though.

Comment: Your first one wouldn't work because it doesn't reference the date.   Well, not that it wouldn't work at all, but it wouldn't satisfy OP's requirement.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I specified it would only work with the given data set.  I added more clarification.  The primary key makes it easier - I'm not sure how to get the date in there for the first one. @TabAlleman

Comment: Fixed the date issue.